# how to call different action methods of one controller from one form in kohana 3.0

Tags: php, kohana-3

I have one form with two buttons (add1,add2). So when I click on button *add1*, I want to call `action_add1()` and clicking button *add2* calls `action_add2()`. Both functions are part of `Controller_Welcome`.
How can I achieve this?

```
class Controller_Welcome extends Controller
{
    public function action_add1()
    {
       //some logic
    }
    public function action_add2()
    {
       //some logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function action_form() 
{
    $action = $this->request->query('action');
    if ($action && method_exists($this, 'action_'.$action))
    {
        $action = 'action_'.$action;
        return $this->$action();
    }
}
```

No Javascript required, just send form data to `welcome/form` with `action` param as button name.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript:

```
<input type="submit" name="add1" />
<input type="submit" name="add2" />

$('input:submit').click(function() {
  $('#myForm').setAttribute('action', 'add_' + this.name);
  $('#myForm').submit();
  return false;
});
```

I'm not sure of the exact syntax, but the main idea is here.